# How to pass state down to child component's handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

The **GeoJson** component has a function **onEachFeature** that calls a handler, in this case it is **createPopup**.

`<GeoJSON data={covidGeoJSON} onEachFeature={createPopup}></GeoJSON>`

Within the handler **createPopup** how can I access states defined inside the CovidMap component?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { MapContainer, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'



CovidMap = ({ covidGeoJSON, styles }) => {

    const showCords = (e) => {
        console.log(e.latlng);
    }

    const createPopup = (state, layer) => {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: showCords,
        });
        layer.bindPopup(state.properties.NAME);
    }

    const [range, setRange] = useState([]);

    return (
        <div>
            <MapContainer style={{ height: '90vh', width: '100vw' }} center={[39.162497380360634, -94.83672007881789]} zoom={5}>
                <GeoJSON data={covidGeoJSON} onEachFeature={createPopup}></GeoJSON>
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CovidMap
```

Comment: Which data are you trying to reach from where? If you are trying to access the `range` state variable in the `createPopup` function, you can just directly access it by name. You can pass down the definition of the `createPopup` handler to your `<GeoJSON />` component, but it is invoked in the scope of where it was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reference the state from `createPopup`. Create & use state variables within `CovidMap` using the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook:

```
const CovidMap = () => {

    ...
    const [properties, setProperties] = useState({});
    const [layer, setLayer] = useState({});

    const createPopup = () => {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: showCords,
        });
        layer.bindPopup(properties.NAME);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Before asking your questions I tried something similar but I defined my states after my handler and it didn't work. If functions are hoisted anyways in javascript then why does the order of definition matter?

Comment: You're right, the order is non-important.